How to use local path for a file stored at my Onedrive?
I have this code
Ruta = Me.Path & "\" & "LISTADO UNIDADES.xls"
If Worksheets("General Reparaciones").Cells(1, 3).Value >= FileDateTime(Ruta) Then

But VBA say me error: argument or call to procedure not valid
That is due Ruta instead have D:\Onedrive|Test\LISTADO UNIDADES.xls it has an URL
https://d.docs.live.net/.../Test/LISTADO UNIDADES.xls

But this is an error, or cause error
How to use local path?
I had read some sites, but seem with old Onedrive client as I have not this interface
{
    "ErrorCode": "platform-invalid",
    "ErrorMessage": "Query string platform:  is not supported",
    "StatusCode": 400
}


This may live in the onedrive application settings. Look for the "Use office application to sync office files that i open" then reopen the workbook and see if that helps

Thanks, today (when return to office pc) I figured it. Workbook was only at cloud. Then by instinct I set the folder test to available at this device. Now me.path return local path

Oops I wrote from office pc that has FOffice 2016. But here at home with Office 365, still me.path send an URL even when I configure folder to be available at this device

It's a bit complex (and I didn't come up with this) but this is what I'd use:
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print GetLocalFile(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)  'or pass a path
End Sub


Function GetLocalFile(wbPath As String) As String
    Const DO_DEBUG As Boolean = True
    
    GetLocalFile = wbPath ' Set default return
    If DO_DEBUG Then Debug.Print GetLocalFile & vbLf & "-----------------"

    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

    Dim strValue As String

    Dim objReg As Object: Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    Dim strRegPath As String: strRegPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    Dim arrSubKeys() As Variant
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath, arrSubKeys

    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In arrSubKeys
        ' check if this key has a value named "UrlNamespace", and save the value to strValue
        objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "UrlNamespace", strValue
        If Len(strValue) > 0 Then
            ' If the namespace is in FullName, then we know we have a URL and need to get the path on disk
            If DO_DEBUG Then Debug.Print "URLNameSpace", strValue
            If InStr(wbPath, strValue) > 0 Then
                Dim strTemp As String
                Dim strCID As String
                Dim strMountpoint As String
            
                ' Get the mount point for OneDrive
                objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "MountPoint", strMountpoint
                If DO_DEBUG Then Debug.Print "mount", strMountpoint
            
                ' Get the CID
                objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "CID", strCID
                If DO_DEBUG Then Debug.Print "CID", strCID
            
                ' strip off the namespace and CID
                If Len(strCID) > 0 Then strValue = strValue & "/" & strCID
                strTemp = Right(wbPath, Len(wbPath) - Len(strValue))
            
                ' replace all forward slashes with backslashes
                GetLocalFile = strMountpoint & "\" & Replace(strTemp, "/", "\")
                If DO_DEBUG Then Debug.Print "--------Found-----------"
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If 'has URL namespace
    Next
End Function

In my testing this is pretty reliable for OneDrive or for a synced SharePoint folder.

Thanks. Maybe at future projects can use it, if workbook is only to use at cloud, shared

A simple solution, probably not for professional use.
My Onedrive address and folders
https://d.docs.live.net/’long_id’/folder1/folder2

I suppose the url is always the same. Then slash before the folders is always the same number. In this case the fourth.
Sub localAdress()
Dim path As String, cSerch As String
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
path = ThisWorkbook.path
Debug.Print path
cSerch = "/"
'find the position of the fourth slash
Do Until InStr(x + 1, path, cSerch) = 0
  x = InStr(x + 1, path, cSerch)
  y = y + 1
  If y = 4 Then Exit Do
Loop
path = CStr(Environ("OneDriveConsumer") & "\") & Replace(Mid(path, x + 1, Len(path) - x), "/", "\")
Debug.Print path
End sub

I have a private OneDrive and a Company OneDrive on the computer, environment variables is:
OneDrive=C:\Users\nn\OneDrive – Company name
OneDriveCommercial=C:\Users\nn\OneDrive - Company name
OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\nn\OneDrive

Print environment variables:
Sub printENV()
Dim EnvString, I as integer
I = 1
Do
    EnvString = Environ(I)
    Debug.Print EnvString
    I = I + 1
Loop Until EnvString = ""
End Sub

